# SharePoint 2013 People Search not working

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, search-scope, contextualscope

On our farm, People searches (this site) return no results while the `"everything"` search center returns results, even results from people.

Some background on the farm:

We have a web app with 2 AAMs, **http://** for the default zone with **NTLM authentication**.  This is only for people on the server and *service applications* to access, the farm is in an enclave that doesn't allow **http://** traffic from the outside.  Allowing **http://** traffic in is not an option.

The extranet AAM uses **https://** and uses **AD FS claims authentication**.  This is the URL that all of our customers access the site from.

The content crawler works fine and is crawling the **http://** version of the web app and receiving results.  I have a server name mapping rule that changes the **http://** to **https://**.  I can look by host name and can see that the mysite host has thousands of index entries, searching by everything brings up results.

The search service account has access to the UPS for search purposes.

Anyone know why it's not returning results when I search under `"People"`?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered there are a number of things you have to check out.

1. Provision User Profile Service and Synchronization (I did this)
2. Configure My Sites with self-service site creation
3. Provision the Search Service Application (I did this)
4. Grant Service application service identity privileges to search for people and profiles inside the UPS (go to Manage service applications, click the row with the UPS, click "administrators" in the ribbon bar, add search service, check the last box at the least) (I did this)
5. Create a content source with sps3://your mysites url as a source/validate sps3://your mysites url exists as a source
6. Make sure it crawls

I don't know if there's something wrong with my farm itself, but it seemed like every time I made a change to the content sources the entire search application became hosed and I would have to delete it and start over.  So in the end I did that and it started working.

The number 1 thing to try with search service seems to be the "kick it if it breaks"

Comment: You may also check out [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2b760f44-3eed-4ab0-96fb-fdccffe0cfdd/explanation-of-protocol-handlers-sts3-and-sps3?forum=sharepointsearchlegacy). if you are using SSL on your My Site host headers, the SPS3 protocol should not be used, and you should change your content source to use the SPS3S protocol instead